# Retrieve JSON response when creating video on Brightcove

Tags: brightcove

I followed the example on http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/references/reference.html#Video. The response gets shown in an iframe. However, I would like to be able to get the JSON response in order to store the data (i.e., Brightcove video ID) in my own database. I tried using AJAX post but Brightcove doesn't seem to accept post requests from a  different origin. Is there a way to simply get the response data without displaying it in an iframe or in a separate window?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the response data in javascript since the API response does not include CORS headers. You'd need to do this in server-side code, which also has the advantage of not exposing your API token to the browser.